# Intuition behind the definition of an irreducible lattice

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

I am reading Dave Witte-Morris' [book on arithmetic groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106063) and having trouble getting a handle on his definition of an irreducible lattice.

A lattice $\Gamma\subset G$ in a semisimple Lie group $G$ is a discrete subgroup such that the quotient $G/\Gamma$ has finite volume (with respect to Haar measure).

In chapter 4.3 an irreducible lattice is defined to be a lattice $\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma N$ is dense in $G$ for every noncompact, closed, normal subgroup $N$ of $G^{\circ}$ (where $G^{\circ}$ is the identity component of $G$).

How does this definition work intuitively and how can I work with it?

My intuition behind a reducible lattice $\Gamma\subset G$ is that it is 'made up' of a product of lattices so that there exists some subgroup $H\le G$ so that $\Gamma\cap H\subset H$ is also a lattice.

I kind of understand that for example $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})\times\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})\subset \mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})\times \mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is reducible. In this case if we consider $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})\times \{I_{n}\}$ then 
$$\left(\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})\times\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})\right)\cap \left(\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})\times \{I_{n}\}\right)= \mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})\times \{I_{n}\}\subset \mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})\times \{I_{n}\}$$ and this is clearly a lattice so it is reducible.

But then why is $\mathrm{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z})\subset \mathrm{SL}_{n}({\mathbb{R}})$ irreducible?

Comment: Hint: How many closed normal subgroups of $SL(n,R)$ do you know?

Comment: It is a simple Lie group, so all normal Lie subgroups are either finite or have finite index.